# Bootstrap navbar, why is my navbar not expanding properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, navbar

Could someone help me fix my navbar ? It is not expanding properly when clicking on the toggler, im sure i've misplaced a div but I have moved around elements with very little success...

```
<header class="site-header" role="banner">
  <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-lg ">
      <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- end button -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" src="index.html"><img class="logo-brand"src="img/kin.jpg" alt="header icon"></a>
    
    <!-- collapsed section -->
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarToggler">
        <!-- ml-auto for right and mr-auto for left -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"  href="#">Activities</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      
    </nav> <!--navbar -->
  </div><!--navbar wrapper-->
</header>
```

I've compared it to a code that works and cannot find the difference... anyone with a good eye to fix me mistake ?
Ive copied a working collapsing navbar in my code and the same thing happens it the wrapper wont expand while the text comes out of its parent

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following example:

Your code has no problem.
Be sure you provide right links for libraries. I added bootstrap css and js library links. And it needs Jquery before bootsrap js link.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header class="site-header" role="banner">
  <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-lg ">
      <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- end button -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" src="index.html"><img class="logo-brand"src="img/kin.jpg" alt="header icon"></a>
    
    <!-- collapsed section -->
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarToggler">
        <!-- ml-auto for right and mr-auto for left -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"  href="#">Activities</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
    </nav> <!--navbar -->
  </div><!--navbar wrapper-->
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

`

Test Home

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1.0" shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

`

Also, do not forget to add the initial stylesheet imports in the head of the HTML document as that stylesheet will play a key role in displaying the page properly. Specifying the width for the device width will allow the html document to adjust to the device width and UTF-8 specifies the character encoding to the HTML interpreter its something that all developers should get into the habit of including!